# Are there any Force users that are "lower life forms"?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

Obviously there are non-human Force users (both Jedi and Sith), all of them that I can recall seeing though are still fairly humanoid and seem to be at a similar intelligence level to humans. However, I doubt that they are all equally intelligent and thus I would assume there is some minimum sentience or intelligence required to be a Force user.

Have there been any instances of what one might call "lower life forms" using the Force? By lower life form I mean something that we could not directly communicate with through speech. So for example a squirrel would probably be too "dumb" to be trained in the Force, but could a smarter animal like a dolphin be trained?